# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync Disble KeepAlive

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to make a POST request to a ASP.NET WEB API.
I want to disable the Keep Alive connections.

How do I disable keep alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly create a `HttpWebRequest` and set its `KeepAlive` property to false:

```
string url = "" //Add your url here

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.KeepAlive = false;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

`HttpClient` wraps the creation of the `HttpWebRequest` for you. But, when you want to more fine-grained control over the request being made, you still have to generate it yourself.

Comment: umm... but then what's the point of using HttpClient because you are using Old HttpWebRequest and WebRequest classes anyway. I thought HttpClient replaces the need for using those classes.

Comment: You're only using them to generate the request since you explicitly need to set properties not avaliable in `HttpClient`, as it wraps the creation of a http request for you